# Missing return statement in method

Tags: java, return

trying to figure this out.  I've created a method that checks if the user has entered an integer using a catch block.

The method obviously is asking for a return statement but no matter where I put it it does not work.  Could anyone offer any advice?

```
public class Week5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        inputInt();
        inputDouble();
    }

    public static int inputInt(){
        Scanner myKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number:");

        int num;

        boolean carryOn = true;

        while (carryOn == true) { 
            {
                try { 
                    num = myKeyboard.nextInt();

                    carryOn = false;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {System.out.println ("Integers only, try again" ); 

                myKeyboard.next();
                return num;    
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would be returned assuming while condition NOT satisfied?

Comment: 1. Please format the code properly (=> remove empty lines). 2. Every path in this method must return something. At the moment, only the `catch` clause has a return statement.

Comment: @Sudhakar this is not right a place for your sarcasm, i would like to see your implementation of reading `ints` from console without `try - catch` in a `while` loop.

Comment: This is not a proper way of writing code. You have mixed exception handling and your actual business logic which makes it first of all unreadable and hard to understand.
try-catch functionality is provided to catch the exceptional situation and not to test the logic.

As for your return statement, what do you want to return at the first place? the non-integer number or the boolean result whether the number entered is integer or not?

Answer (score 5):

When `carryOn` == false then it will go to the bottom of your method and there's no return statement there.  You need to have a return statement at the bottom.

Here's an explanation of the error:  If a function says it returns something (an `int` in this case) that means that every path it can take must return an `int`.  You're missing one of those paths which is a compile time error.